# Create a single partition from 2 hard drives Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, partitioning, raid

I have 2x 3TB identical drives and i want to make a single 6TB partition from both drives so i don't have to keep copying files between the drives. ( i know if 1 drive fails i'll lose everything but i have backups )

When i try and make a striped partition in windows disk management i add the 2 drives there but it will only let me make the available disk space the maximum of 1 drive.

Is there something i'm doing wrong ?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're really close. If you want the full capacity without redundancy then you need to select the option for a **spanned** volume, not striped.

Comment: Striped will also use the capacity of both disks. You're thinking of mirrored.

Answer (score 2):

In the Windows Disk Manager you'll want to use the Extend Volume option and span the volume across the two drives.  This will create a logical extent on the drives and should allow you to make a 6TB (minus partitioning) volume.  Here is a link to Microsoft's article on the matter:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753058.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If USB drives on Windows 8, look at storage spaces. If USB drives pre-Windows 8 you need 3rd party software - the free versions of which are extremely clunky.